# Optional parameter in .net route beginning

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, configuration, routes

there's

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I want to make my url to allow enter company name in the beginning, e.g.:

```
url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

So I could navigate through pages and now that the base is some company.

- domain.com/company-ltd
- domain.com/company-ltd/products
- domain.com/company-ltd/edit
- domain.com/some-other-company-name-ltd/products

and so on.

How could I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry you cannot have optional route parameters at the beginning. Only the last parameter in a route can be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes work off the back of patterns; a URL coming in is matched against patterns until one is found that it matches.

Assuming that you're not talking about optional company names, you should be able to get away with:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default With company",
        url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
  );
```

and then simply ensure that all methods take a `company` parameter. However, this would fail on more simple routes, so make sure you set a default for pages such as the root. If you do end up wanting additional routes that don't involve a company, those can also be catered for with controller-specific routes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Profile",
        url: "profile/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
  );
```

before the less-specific company one.

Note that you can test these routes quite easily in .net using NUnit and MvcContrib.TestHelper, for example:

```
"~/company/".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Get)
            .ShouldMapTo<Controller.HomeController>(x => 
                  x.Index("company"));

"~/company/products/".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Get)
            .ShouldMapTo<Controller.ProductsController>(x => 
                  x.Index("company"));
```

to ensure that they're going to the locations you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. But if e.g. I want to have domain.com/profile for user who is using current portal and is not related to company, would this approach work? To clarify: domain.com/profile - user can edit his name, photo etc... domain.com/search - user can search for companies... domain.com/company-name-ltd/products - user can view specific company stuff

Comment: You could, but you would have to have a different route defined before this one, with a url of (something like - it depends on your actual requirements) "profile/{action}" and a default controller of 'Profile'.

Comment: I have tested it with link http://localhost:22621/test/Company/Index
There are now those two routes:

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =     UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default With Company Name",
    url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {  controller = "Company", action = "Index", id =     UrlParameter.Optional });

And I get: The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Order is important. Your URL is being picked up by the 'Default' route, creating a TestController, and calling Company("Index") on it. The more generic a route is, the later it should go.

Comment: The idea is to make it like in github when you see username right after domain and than other contollers/actions. I have done this in node.js, hope this would not be so much complicated in .net :)

Comment: I switched order and now it can't find  /Account/Manage (generated by default on new project)

Comment: As I said in my answer, you may need to manually add routes for controllers that do not take the company name as a prefix. You're trying to add an optional parameter at the beginning of a URL, which means you are having to make compromises elsewhere.

Comment: Excellent! I have got this:) I'll place username everywhere where's more personalized data for user and place company name where should be company data. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: You could, as an alternative, have URLs such as /company/[Company Name]/other-stuff - this would make your rule "/company/{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" and allow you to keep other URLs as default. But I'm aware that that's a change to your original requirements.

Comment: Happy to have helped. :)